# Link a Static Page in Twig (Sylius)

Tags: php, symfony, routes, sylius

I am using the latest Sylius and I created a static page in the backend.

The internal name is `ueber-uns` and I created a route that links there. So when I browse `mywebsite.com/ueber-uns` it works.

Now I'm having trouble to generate a route for it in my Twig template. The only thing I came up with was this:

`<a href="{{ path('sylius_static_content_show', {'path': 'uber-uns'}) }}">Über uns</a>` but this throws a

> Route 'sylius_static_content_show' not found" error.

The only page I found in the docs was emtpy: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/content.html?highlight=static

Anywhere else I can find information about that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `name` instead of `path` in the arguments for the route

```
<a href="{{ path('sylius_static_content_show', {'name': 'uber-uns'}) }}">Über uns</a>
```

This is the route definition in ShopBundle

```
sylius_shop_static_content_show:
    path: /{name}
    methods: [GET]
    defaults:
        _controller: sylius.controller.static_content:showAction
        _sylius:
            template: SyliusShopBundle:StaticContent:show.html.twig
            repository:
                method: findPublishedOneByName
                arguments: [$name]
```